# Nonzero elements of spectrum of compact normal operator is an eigenvalue

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to prove that $H$ is a Hilbert space, $T:H\to H$ is  a compact normal operator, and $0\neq \lambda \in \sigma(T)$, then there is $x\in H$ such that $Hx=\lambda x$.

I have no idea where to start. Please give me any hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theory_of_compact_operators

Comment: When you say  $\sigma (T) $ you mean the spectrum in which banach algebra? The algebra of bounded operators?

Comment: Which theorems about the spectrum of bounded/compact operators do you know?

Comment: I know that for a compact self-adjoint operator T, T is always a summation of contant times projections to its eigenspaces. I guess this is the strongest theorem I know.

Comment: @OrKedar I am not sure what you meant. The only definition I know is a set of complex numbers $\lambda$ which makes $\lambda-T$ is not invertible.